# Inquirer on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, module, inquirer

```
PS D:\Cursos\nodeudemy\aulas\2_FUNDAMENTOS\10_abstracao_input> node index.js
D:\Cursos\nodeudemy\aulas\2_FUNDAMENTOS\10_abstracao_input\index.js:1
const inquirer = require('inquirer')
                 ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\Cursos\nodeudemy\aulas\2_FUNDAMENTOS\10_abstracao_input\node_modules\inquirer\lib\inquirer.js from D:\Cursos\nodeudemy\aulas\2_FUNDAMENTOS\10_abstracao_input\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of inquirer.js in D:\Cursos\nodeudemy\aulas\2_FUNDAMENTOS\10_abstracao_input\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Cursos\nodeudemy\aulas\2_FUNDAMENTOS\10_abstracao_input\index.js:1:18) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

It happens every time i try to run a node file w/ inquirer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js#readme) it explains you this problem and it provides a link on how to solve the issue.

> Inquirer v9 and higher are native esm modules, this mean you cannot
> use the commonjs syntax `require('inquirer')` anymore. If you want to
> learn more about using native esm in Node, I'd recommend reading [the
> following
> guide](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c).
> Alternatively, you can rely on an older version until you're ready to
> upgrade your environment:
>
> ```
> npm install --save inquirer@^8.0.0
> ```
>
> This will then allow import inquirer with the commonjs require:
>
> ```
> const inquirer = require('inquirer');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents here, upgrading to [yarn 3](https://yarnpkg.com/migration/guide) worked for me!